# $\eta \sum_{l=a h+b+1}^{\infty} \gamma^{l} \lambda^{l}=\eta(\gamma \lambda)^{a h+b+1}(1-\gamma \lambda)^{-1}$?

Tags: limits

I read the paper ["link prediction based on graph neural networks"](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2018/file/53f0d7c537d99b3824f0f99d62ea2428-Paper.pdf), In Theorem 2 of this paper, it use:
$$\eta \sum_{l=a h+b+1}^{\infty} \gamma^{l} \lambda^{l}=\eta(\gamma \lambda)^{a h+b+1}(1-\gamma \lambda)^{-1}$$

where $\gamma$ is a decaying factor between 0 and 1, $\lambda < \frac{1}{\gamma}$. $\eta$ is a positive constant or a positive function of $\gamma$ that is upper bounded by a constant, $a, b \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a > 0$, $h$ is a positive integer. I can not understand why the equation holds.

Comment: What is $h$? Is it a variable on the LHS? If yes, then why is it on the RHS? If no, that what's the summation of $l$ taken over?

Comment: I suspect what they are doing is just $ ( 1 - x)^(-1) = 1 + x + x^2 + \ldots $, esp if the sum is over $ l = ah + b + i$ where $i$ is a positive integer.

Comment: @CalvinLin Thanks a lot, you are right. I asked a naive question